Android Studio / Kotlin: Which code formatter rule controls indentation of this line?
I have the following piece of Kotlin code:
fun test(
    param: Pam<
        ParamPam,
        Param,
        PamParam
        > // which formatting rule controls indentation of this line?
) {
}

and I cannot get it to be formatted like this:
fun test(
    param: Pam<
        ParamPam,
        Param,
        PamParam
    > // indentation level should match starting '<', like indentation of {} and ()
) {
}

I suspect it's one of the indentation continuation rules but cannot pinpoint the exact one.
